# Why do two relations when divided become an equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have problems with understanding how to operate with proportionality the first problem is with a question above.

Say we have two relations A proportional to B and C is proportional to D then if we divide the two relations why do we get A upon C is equals to B upon D and not A/C = KB/QD k and q being some numbers

Another question is why can a term be substituted in one relation from another for example:-

```
   a is proportional to p
   a + (n-1)x is proportional to q
   Then why is
   p + (n-1)x proportional to q
```

Also,
Why can we substitute relations in equations

I don't seem to understand how proportionality works if there are any other rules for applications that I've missed can you also please tell me those?

Comment: No wonder you don't understand this. The claim is false in general.

Answer (score 0):

The relation "$a$ is proportional to $b$" actually represents an equation already, namely: $a=k\cdot b$ for some number $k$. So all of the rules of equal signs can be used, including transitivity and substitution.

Comment: Then why in the relations given in question, a is substituted by p and not kp.

Comment: Say we have two relations A proportional to B and C is proportional to D then if we divide the two relations why do we get A upon C is equals to B upon D and not A/C = KB/QD k and q being some numbers

Answer (score 0):

Saying that one variable is proportional to another is simply another way os saying that there is a linear relationship between them. In other words the following statements:

1. $a$ is proportional to $b$
2. $a=kb$ for some constant $k$
3. $\frac{a}{b}=k$ for some constant $k$

all say the same thing.

If $a$ is proportional to $b$ and $a$ is also proportional to $c$, then we have $a=k_1b$ and $a=k_2c$. So $b=\frac{k_2}{k_1}c$. But since $k_1$ and $k_2$ are constants then so is $\frac{k_2}{k_1}$. So we can conclude that $b$ is proportional to $c$.